# Named query join select

Tags: mysql, jpa, select

I need to get GroupEntity objects which have assigned specific role in RoleGroupEntity Table.

I try to do this like that:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "GroupEntity.getGIDs", query = "SELECT o FROM RoleGroupEntity u JOIN FETCH u.GroupId o WHERE u.role_id LIKE :role_id")
```

but I got:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: role_id of: RoleGroupEntity
```

Entites sample:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class GroupEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "gid_number")
    private Long gid_number;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "GroupId")
    private List<RoleGroupEntity> GroupId;
```

RoleGroupEntity has Composite Key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_group")
public class RoleGroupEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private RoleGroupCompositeKey posRGKey;

    @MapsId("role_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private RoleEntity roles;

    @MapsId("group_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private GroupEntity GroupId;
```

Do you know how to make my select query to work?

Comment: There is no property "role_id" in RoleGroupEntity as the message says. JPQL uses field/property names NOT column names. JPQL != SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the joincolumn you have to use: `u.roles.id LIKE :role_id")`

```
@NamedQuery(name = "GroupEntity.getGIDs", query = "SELECT o FROM RoleGroupEntity u JOIN FETCH u.GroupId o WHERE u.roles.id LIKE :role_id")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got `QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties`

Comment: use an `inner join` instead of `join fetch`

Comment: I changed JOIN FETCH to just JOIN and used your select and it worked well, so thank you very much both of you.